# Explode string to two string

Tags: php, regex

I have string:

```
$local->string = '@John Smith: I have: milk, cookies and wine';
```

And I want explode this to two string. First 'John Smith' and second 'I have: milk, cookies and wine'. I can use explode, but when I write:

```
explode(':', $local->string);
```

I get:

1. @John Smith
2. (space)I have
3. (space)milk, cookies and wine

I know it's regexp way to result this, but I dont know regexp :-/

Please, help me :)

Comment: Add additional argument specifying the max amount of elements after the split, e.g. 2 here.

Comment: What about learning regex? :P

Comment: `$e = explode(':', $local->string);`
`echo $e[0].$e[1]` `echo $e[2]`

Comment: @Simon_eQ: But ten i have more ":" in string this code dont work ;)

Comment: @KubaŻukowski Just put some effort into it. I can see this is requires a minimal effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard with a regex.  Assuming your string is *always* `@<name>: <text>`, then you can try this:

```
/@(.*?): (.*)/
```

Then you can use that with `preg_match()`:

```
if(preg_match('/@(.*?): (.*)/', $local->string, $match) > 0){
    // These will be your matched groups
    echo $match[1];  // the name
    echo $match[2];  // the text
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$limit` parameter of the function, as you can find in the [documentation](http://php.net/explode):

```
$local->string = '@John Smith: I have: milk, cookies and wine';
$temp = explode (':', $local -> string, 2);
```

---

When you want to learn regex (which is a great idea), go to this page: http://regexone.com/. Great tutorial. But, always remember to make sure you know which tools to use at which time. In this situation, the `explode(...)` function is clearly enough to suit your needs.

Comment: It needs to be two :)

Comment: I forgot about the 3rd parameter to `explode()`!  +1

Answer (score 1):

```
explode(':', $local->string, 2);
```

just look at the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

There has already been an answer I will just offer another solution:

```
$string = '@John Smith: I have: milk, cookies and wine';
list($name, $items) = explode(":", $string, 2);
```

This will assign `$name` the first section, and `$items` the second. This can be useful if you don't want an array returned and know there will always be X results (2 in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex for that. Just search for the first position of the `:` character:

```
$local->string = '@John Smith: I have: milk, cookies and wine';
$pos = strpos($local->string, ':');

if (false !== $pos) {
    $firstPart = substr($local->string, 0, $pos);
    $secondPart = substr($local->string, $pos + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the limit as the third parameter of explode that will do the job.

```
$split = explode(':', '@John Smith: I have: milk, cookies and wine', 2);
echo $split[1]; //output ' I have: milk, cookies and wine'
```

You just have to remove the @ and the first space, that is, remove the first character in each split

Answer (score 0):

If you dont know regex keep it simple

```
$string = '@John Smith: I have: milk, cookies and wine';

$t = explode(':', $string, 2);

$t[0] = str_replace( '@', '', $t[0] );
$t[1] = str_replace( ':', '', $t[1] );
$t[1] = trim($t[1]);
```

So

```
Array
(
    [0] => John Smith
    [1] => I have milk, cookies and wine
)
```